"What can I use in place of &lt; and &gt; in HTML?"
I am trying to display < and > symbols as plain text in an HTML document, but they get interpreted as HTML tags. I used &lt; and &gt;, which work fine, but I'm wondering if there are alternative methods to achieve the same result.
<p>This is an example of &lt;code&gt; in HTML.</p>

This works, but is there a simpler or more modern way to escape these characters? Are there other character entities or methods I can use?

⟨ https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+27E8

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The current HTML standard still uses &lt; and &gt;, and there is no indication that these are or will be deprecated, nor are there any other alternatives (other than, perhaps, using their code point numbers).
